# How to redirect to the first modal when submit button on the second modal clicked using Laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have a button on the first modal to add a list in my dropdownlist. When it clicked, it shows the second modal and the first modal is closed. And I want when I clicked the submit button on the second modal, the data is insert into the database and then the second modal is closed and the first modal shows with the new added list in my dropdownlist.

If I am using this code as the submit button on the second modal, after submit the modal is closed and the first modal showed, but the data won't saved to the database.

```
<button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#first_modal" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-round btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
```

And if I am using this code, the data is saved perfectly into the database, but it will redirect me into the main page, not into the first modal.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
```

This is the submit function in my controller.

```
public function AddClientLead(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client;
    $client->CLI_CLIENTCODE = $request['cli_code'];
    $client->CLI_CLIENTNAME = $request['cli_name'];
    $client->CLI_ADDRESS = $request['cli_address'];
    $client->CLI_PHONE = $request['cli_phone'];
    $client->CLI_EMAIL = $request['cli_email'];
    $client->CLI_WEBSITE = $request['cli_website'];
    $client->CLI_REMARK = $request['cli_remark'];
    $client->CLI_CREATEDBY = 'HPT';
    $client->CLI_CREATEDDATE = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $client->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your first modal is being shown, check whether it is being triggered by the second model's button

```
$('#first_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var source = button.data('source') // Extract info from data-* attributes

    if (source == 'second-modal') {
        // Get the form data and send it to server via ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: "AddClientLead", // YOUR ROUTE URL
            type: "get", // SHOULD MATCH THE TYPE WITH YOUR ROUTE DEFINITION
            cache: false,
            data: $("#second-form").serialize(); // second form's handle
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also modify your second modal's button as

```
<button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#first_modal" 
        data-dismiss="modal" data-source="second-modal"
        class="btn btn-round btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
```

and do add `data-source` to your first modal's button as `data-source="first-modal"`

Finally, instead of returing a `redirect` from the controller you could return the persisted object so that it would be available to your ajax's success callback function.

```
public function AddClientLead(Request $request)
{
    ...

    return response()->json($client);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but I get null value when I am trying to save every `$request['.........']` in my controller. This is my ajax `$.ajax({
        url: "AddClientLead",
        type: "get",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
        }` And this null is not in the list in the first modal after the second modal closed. I need to refresh the page and open again the first modal to make it exist on the list

Comment: @hendraspt So the record is saved, but not appended to the list ?

Comment: yeah saved but all is a null value and not appended to the list too. When I show the value of `source` in the console, it shows `second-modal` . Do I need to change something in your `var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    var source = button.data('source')` code?

Comment: I don't see the `data` attribute in your ajax, because of which null data is saved. Add the `data` attribute to your ajax and attach the form data to the data attribute

Comment: sorry, what do you mean of "attach the form data" ? I don't quite understand about ajax though, I'm still learning about it.

Comment: @hendraspt I've updated my answer, though it's pseudo code, use your best judgement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165623/discussion-between-hendraspt-and-linktoahref).